# Performance issue with geometry table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry

I am on SQL Server 11. I have the following table that stores the boundary of all LGA in NSW

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[nsw_lga_polygon_shp](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [geom] [geometry] NULL,
    [lg_ply_pid] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [dt_create] [date] NULL,
    [dt_retire] [date] NULL,
    [lga_pid] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [nsw_lga_sh] [date] NULL,
    [nsw_lga__1] [date] NULL,
    [nsw_lga__2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [nsw_lga__3] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [nsw_lga__4] [date] NULL,
    [nsw_lga__5] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_nsw_lga_polygon_shp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[nsw_lga_polygon_shp] ON;
```

The table only have 198 rows

When I try to map the result against one of my table that have 36,531 rows, I notice that it have very serious performance issue, it told 5 mins to generate 500 rows.

```
select 
    * ,
    (select top 1

    nsw_lga__2
from 
    [nsw_lga_polygon_shp]
where

    Geom.Filter(geometry::STGeomFromText('point(' +
        convert(varchar(100),longitude_GIS )+ 
        ' ' + 
        cast(latitude_GIS as varchar(100))+ ')',4283)) = 1 
    ) LGA
from 
    Report_A
```

Is there anyway I can may it run faster? Can I index the geometry column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried spatial index?

Comment: I am trying, but I cannot identify the right parameter for the bounding box

Comment: Do you have an explicit reason for using the geometry datatype instead of geography for geographic data?

Comment: @Ben, The reason why I am using geometry is pure because the digital map data I have is using geometry.

Comment: I would guess that having to convert from long/lat to `geometry` for every row is costing you. Can you make your table have a `geometry` column?